# Visualizing RandomForestRegression trees

Tags: scikit-learn, pydot

I have run a RandomForestRegression model in sklearn and saved the output of my decisions trees (n_estimators=50) into 50 `.dot` files.

Now I want to save them so I can view them as actual trees.

I am trying this:

```py
import pydotplus

dot_data=r'F:\Sheyenne\Random_Forest\my_tree0.dot'

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data) 

graph.write_pdf(r'F:\Sheyenne\Random_Forest\my_tree0.pdf')
```

but this returns:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_pdf'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to load a file. Try this:

```py
import pydotplus

dot_file=r'F:\Sheyenne\Random_Forest\my_tree0.dot'

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_file(dot_file) 

graph.write_pdf(r'F:\Sheyenne\Random_Forest\my_tree0.pdf')
```